# php function re-declare error

Tags: php

I have a small code which is bound in a function and is used to generate user level tags. For example if Database permission for specific user is set to 9 he/she is Admin if its 0 he/she is a Member and so on.

Here is the function

```
function user_level($user_level) {
                 if($user_level == 10) {
                     $level = "<span style='color:#fff;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000;font-size:14px;background:#065286;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px;'>System Root</span>";
                 } elseif($user_level == 9) {
                     $level = "<span style='color:#fff;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000;font-size:14px;background:#df4d28;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px;'>Admin</span>";
                 } else {
                     $level = "<span style='color:#fff;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000;font-size:14px;background:#008CD7;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px;'>Member</span>";
                 }
                 return $level;
            }

            $level = user_level($user_level);
```

Now this function is used inside a custom forum script so ones initial post is made lets assume there is a reply.

Sadly the reply is not show but instead I am given

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare user_level() (previously declared in /home/u688392685/public_html/comet/viewtopic.php:156) in /home/u688392685/public_html/comet/viewtopic.php on line 156
```

I am not sure whats going on because it worked fine before, I recall host doing some PHP changes like version updating but thats all. Any way to fix this issue and get me back on track?

If relative: Apache/2.2.14, PHP 5.2.x

Comment: Check `public_html/comet/viewtopic.php`, line 156?

Comment: @Tushar the function is in viewtopic.php

Comment: Don't include that script twice. Or move your function elsewhere, if it's actually supposed to be a template/output script.

Comment: @Random are you using `include_once` and `require_once` everywhere?

Comment: Also, please lose the inline CSS and move them to a stylesheet. `<span class="admin user">Admin</span>` looks so much better, and you can style it with `.admin.user { /* set attributes in here */ }`

Comment: @Tushar actually no I was not using it but now I move the function to a function directory and used include_once(functions/user-level.php); and have that in vietopic.php and this seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for help.

Based on @Mario suggestion I moved the function into a directory and using

> include_once

Inserted the function into viewtopic.php

Answer (score 2):

The php file containing the function is probably included twice in your scripts.

You can fix this issue by replacing any occurence of `include(file.php);` or `require(file.php);` by respectively `include_once(file.php);`  or `require_once(file.php);`.

Comment: It was directly inserted into viewtopic.php now I fixed that thanks for the reply.